# WSO2 IS Unable to access ouside

Tags: wso2-identity-server

https://medium.com/@buddhimau/explaining-simple-wso2-identity-server-kubernetes-deployment-5e251ca189e2
followed the link as is.
Issue 1:unable to access with domain than rather i can access with domain:port like domain with node port.How do i need to avoid it and put my domain
Example:https://wso2is:32124/carbon/admin/login.jsp but want to access https://wso2is/carbon/admin/login.jsp
.How do i need to add my jks file.which already created externally.how to pass it
in config map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. By following the above tutorial if you cannot access the management console as https://wso2is/carbon/admin/login.jsp. Then there should be a issue in your load balancing. use

> *kubectl get ing -n wso2*

Command to get the ingress it should be exposed with the port 443 and there should be minikube ip in the ip address column. If this does not seems right use

> *kubectl describe ing wso2is-ingress -n wso2*

And

> *kubectl logs  -n kube-system*

For debugging.

2. jks files need to be provided as secrets not as config maps. You can refer this blog to get some idea https://www.padok.fr/en/blog/kubernetes-secrets

Comment: but  IP doens't generate for ingress controller in kubernetes setup.Is their any different kubernetes ingress to be deployment rather minikube? i see the blank space with no IP

Comment: created secrest where updated jks secret over.and m ounted as below with example.but unable to mount the jks file and pod is not getting started                   olumeMounts:
            - name: secrets
          mountPath: /home/wso2carbon/wso2is-5.10.0/repository/resources/security
          readOnly: true - name: secrets
        secret:
            secretName: "my-secret"
            items:
              - key: wso2carbon.jks
                path: wso2carbon.jks

Comment: @ Buddhima Udaranag! I have Db configured Outside like in windows server Postgress can i give the connections in the Deployment toml and access instead of H2 Db. i used to have postgress connector in /repo/component/lib how to pass a file? like eg postgressql.jar connect or db.I have ran the respective files mentioned in the link given wso2 ref.How do i need to send the postgress connector inside the pod!